# libstdc++6 : Breaks: libboost-date-time1.54.0

Tags: linux-mint

I encountered an error related to unmet dependencies: libstdc++6 : Breaks: libboost-date-time1.54.0 but 1.54.0-4ubuntu3.1 is to be installed.

I found that I have manual installation of libstdc++6.

```
 $ apt-cache policy libstdc++6
    libstdc++6:
      Installed: 8-20180331-1
      Candidate: 8-20180331-1
      Version table:
     *** 8-20180331-1 0
            100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
         4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.4 0
            500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main amd64 Packages
            500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security/main amd64 Packages
         4.8.2-19ubuntu1 0
            500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages

gcc (Ubuntu 4.8.5-2ubuntu1~14.04.1) 4.8.5
Copyright (C) 2015 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

    gcc-4.8:
      Installed: 4.8.5-2ubuntu1~14.04.1
      Candidate: 4.8.5-2ubuntu1~14.04.1
      Version table:
     *** 4.8.5-2ubuntu1~14.04.1 0
            100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
         4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.4 0
            500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main amd64 Packages
            500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security/main amd64 Packages
         4.8.2-19ubuntu1 0
            500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
```

I am unable to install libreoffice and many other softwares because of these dependency issues. How to fix this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You’re running a newer version of `libstdc++6` than is provided by your distribution. If you want to use your distribution’s packages correctly, you should revert:

```
sudo apt install libstdc++6=4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.4
```